# Getting an index out of bounds error and I don't know why. I'm stuck

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, iteration

I am getting an index out of bounds exception in Scala and I have no idea why.

```
val rawData = "4x23x21\n22x29x19\n11x4x11\n8x10x5"
val data = rawData.split('\n')
data.map(x => x.split('x')(1))
```

For some reason I get an array out of bounds exception when I reference the array made when I split x. It should be an array which contains three indexes yet I get the exception when I try and reference the second one. It works perfectly when I reference the first one.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code works for me with (1), which is the second element, as dth points out. It also works with (2) for the third one. So can you post your code that gets the exception, as it's not the code you have in your question.

Comment: It seems that if I shorten the input data it works. The original input data is much longer and when I use that it throws it? Maybe the error is in the data

Comment: can you give us the complete data?

Comment: Here is the data - http://adventofcode.com/day/2/input

Comment: you cannot link to this page... you have to put it somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine:

```
scala> val rawData = "4x23x21\n22x29x19\n11x4x11\n8x10x5"
rawData: String =
4x23x21
22x29x19
11x4x11
8x10x5

scala> val data = rawData.split('\n')
data: Array[String] = Array(4x23x21, 22x29x19, 11x4x11, 8x10x5)

scala> data.map(x => x.split('x')(1))
res0: Array[String] = Array(23, 29, 4, 10)
```

Comment: Yes, and? The OP's array has three entries, so even a mistaken (2) should (and does) work. So the problem must be something else.

Comment: Yes, i've misread, thought he wanted to access the third one and the code was actually his example for accessing the first one. The code runs just fine. So he must be doing something wrong with his input or his indices that he is not showing us. I will edit or remove my answer once we hear back from him

Comment: You are doing something else wrong. Just start REPL (type scala on command line) and paste your code. You'll see it executes just fine.

Comment: Im starting to think there might be something wrong with my data. When I plug it in it gives me the exception. When less data is used (as in my example) it works. Here is the data - http://adventofcode.com/day/2/input

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was in my data! Thank you so much for your help!